# get size from vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, ifstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("text.txt");
    int value;
    string line;
    vector<float> myVector;

    getline(myfile, line);
    istringstream iss(line);
    int n;
    while (iss >> n)
    {
        myVector.push_back(n);
    }
    cout << myVector.size() << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I'm very confused here. If my text file is 10 20 30 40 then the output will be 4, but if my text file is 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 then my output is 1. How can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to use your debugger and step through the code line by line while examining your variables.

Comment: `n` has type `int`.   `iss >> n` will stop at the first `'.'`, set the stream to an error state (so the loop will end) and leave the `'.'` (and all subsequent input) in the input buffer.   Simple fix : change the type of `n` to be `float`.

Answer (score 4):

Simple, if your file has floats then read floats

```
float n; // changed from int
while (iss >> n)
{
    myVector.push_back(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains `1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0` you'll only be able to extract *one* `int` (your `n`) from it, the first `1`. The `failbit` will then be set when it reaches `.` and nothing else will be extracted. If you have floating point values in the file, use `float n`, `double n` or `long double n`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a number into an integer stops when a character is encountered which cannot be part of a whole number; in your case, it's the first dot. The next read attempt encounters the same dot and fails immediately; the stream's status should have the fail bit set which must be cleared before further read attempts can succeed (for example, reading a float should succeed because ".0" is a valid text representation of floating point number of the value 0).

You can (and should, because you would want to handle that)  detect wrong input by checking the status of the stream in detail; cppreference has an [overview](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) of the status bit values depending on the stream state. In your case: If the input was read to the end, *only* the eof bit should be set; if input was encountered which cannot be parsed (but the input device was otherwise working), *only* the fail bit should be set.